# Script for a button in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a button that does the following:

A.  Copy a group of columns from sheet 1 (daily sports) and paste them into sheet 2 (Record).

B.  The columns pasted in sheet 2 go to the next empty column (or create a new column) so they don't over-right the info that's already there..

C.  Every time I'm done putting in new information I press the button and it automatically gets copied to sheet 2.

This is the code I'm using:

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var source = ss.getRange ("Daily sports!B2:D20");
var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Record");
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow(),1);
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastColumn(),2);
source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
source.clear ();}
```

The problems I'm having are as follows

1) Every time I hit the button it does not create a new column, instead it just covers the old columns.
2) the original source gets cleared (I know, It's the last function, it clearly says "clear" I just don't know what to write instead... I want the source to stay as is)

If anyone could help me with this script that would be great..
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what are you looking for:

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Daily sports!B2:D20");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Record");
  var row = 1; //the starting row of the range
  var column = destSheet.getLastColumn()+1; //the starting column of the range
  var numRows = 19; //the number of rows to return
  var numColumns = 3; //the number of columns to return
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns);
  source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true})  
}
```